# How to get the messages from threads within Conversation from Facebook Workplace Graph API

Tags: facebook, rest, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I'm using facebook Workplace Graph API.
I'm looking for two things:

1) How to get the messages from message ID
2) How to get the new message only.

What I have done so far?
1) I'm able to get the messages for each convo through this api 
      https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/conversations?fields=messages{message,attachments,from} and it is returning all convo and messgaes together.

I want to get the messages in sequential manner like they have even mentioned in their document : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/community#examples

With this API :

https://graph.facebook.com/Thread_id/messages?user=user_id
This api is returning message id in below format:

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAAAAB3Zz_JwhPe3PFqU7JtwhKkY",
            "created_time": "2019-04-25T08:52:43+0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAAAAB3Zz_JwhOZDsVqU6D6aTMok",
            "created_time": "2019-04-25T08:33:40+0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAAAAB3Zz_JwhOIeqVqU5zVO0W_t",
            "created_time": "2019-04-25T08:29:08+0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAAAAB3Zz_JwhOGJq1qU5xAa27DB",
            "created_time": "2019-04-25T08:28:30+0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "m_mid.$cAAAAAB3Zz_JwhOF-BlqU5wyRZs39",
            "created_time": "2019-04-25T08:28:27+0000"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUjBadUdDcHV6SWRrQkhpQy1iUURYa3lKZADRGR3ZA1RDRIOEE2LWp3aERiRXZAPbWxORFBKOWRWdXBpOWQySWx3TjdxSHpsQm0tRmpNNTc1dnBfV1JYNDFRWmtLbC1QSW5jVkk4a0NUNUF1RUNuemhxUUYzWkllVE9tWkM0Y2tpY1A4",
            "after": "QVFIUnRlc3VPUEdLM2FQdWxob1Y0YWxhdWFrMGQwWUxHSVZAwbmlaZA015RlUwLWRWTHhsdjRnNi03MTl3eWJvMUxiNXBaUFd4bVVBWkhpbmFCYkNLdzR5YlJVZA3YyT1RMVnJIY2JLbXVyTjNaN1pBaWVFeEkta0NLazljUHc5WGhEQlo0"
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to use these message Ids to get the actual message.

Comment: Make a request using the message id, and request the `message` field …?

Comment: @04FS I tried this : message_id?fields=message 
But it's not working.

Comment: Meaning …? No data, error message, …?

Answer (score 0):

to read users' messages you need to use an impersonate_token.
This allows you to see also the content of the message and to use that thread_id.

To read a message, you don't need to call the thread_id, since you can use nested calls, like:

me/conversations?fields=thread_id,messages{message,created_time}

In any case, once you have impersonated a user and retrieved the thread_id, you can do this call

{thread_id}?fields=messages{message,created_time}

to read all the messages of a specific thread. Messages are already ordered by creation_time, so you just need to take the last one.